# Find probabilities using normal distribution

Tags: probability

X is a normally distributed random variable with mean 62 and standard deviation 8. What is the probability that X is greater than 70? Write your answer as a decimal rounded to the nearest thousandth.

Answer (score 0):

$X \sim N(62,8^2)$

$Pr(X>70) = Pr(\frac{X-62}{8}>\frac{70-62}{8}=1) = Pr(Z>1) = 0.1586553 \approx 0.159$, where $Z$ is the standard normal.

---

For any $Y \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, after standardisation, $\frac{Y-\mu}{\sigma} \sim N(0,1)$